# Getting the error "Warning: Prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` did not match." while trying to use script tags in Remix

Tags: javascript, remix, remix.run

I try to run some code for initialising and preload some code in my Remix app. I get this error: "Warning: Prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` did not match. Server:...". I've set my script tag in `head`, and it seems I always get this error when running my script tag.. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

```
<head>
  <script
  key="initialising"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `... some code`,
  }}
  />
</head>
```

Most of the other threads I see are not using the script tag, so I'm not sure where to look for an answer

I've tried to add it to the handle function using remix-utils, but it seems like it loads the script too late.. when this is a script I wanna run as the very first thing

Comment: I had a similar problem with trying to add Google Tag Manager. There is an open issue with React 18.2, but I found this Remix stack that seems to get around the issue via the `suppressHydrationWarning` attribute. That worked for me. I also like how they created a GoogleAnalytics component to kind of abstract that stuff: https://github.dev/meza/trance-stack/blob/main/src/root.tsx

Comment: have you tried wrapping it with ```ClientOnly``` from remix-utils?